# Google colab console to flask?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory

In my Colab project the yolov4 runs in cloud with Realtime webcam! now my question is how to display that console output in flask. Thank you!

Comment: You can use [flask-ngrok](https://medium.com/@kshitijvijay271199/flask-on-google-colab-f6525986797b)

Comment: i have flask but i dont know how to return the console window

Comment: this is my colab code to do yolov4 an realtime video in cloud https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cQa5cBGF8Vouw-fLvS666-V_6zZ4vHO0?usp=sharing
now with flask i need to display the output window to a ngrok  page can someone help me with this please ping me.Thank you!